# Recovering files from BSOD on Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I receive a BSOD when I try to turn on my Windows 10 machine. Any ideas how I can get to my files so that I can back them up?

I've unplugged all peripherals apart from a keyboard. Tried starting in safe mode. I've checked that the hard drive is at the top of the boot devices list in the BIOS. Also, I don't have the original Windows 10 installation files.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have many options. Here are a few:

- Create a Windows 10 Install USB and use it to recover.
  I know you've said that you do not have the original installation files, but you can obtain them from [Microsoft’s own website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) in ISO form or use the Media Creation Tool to create a bootable USB drive. Once that is done, set that as first in the boot sequence in the BIOS and boot from it, then select Repair Your Computer and you’re off.
- Boot from a USB with DSL and back up files from there.
  As above, you would have to [put DSL on a USB](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/installing_to_a_usb_flash_drive.html) and boot from it. From there, you can mount your Windows drive, find your files, and copy them off to your backup location.
- Plug your drive with the files you want to recover into a different (working) computer and back up files from there.
  You will likely need to take apart your non-working machine to get the boot drive out, and then either take apart the working machine or buy a USB adapter for the interface your boot drive uses (SATA/IDE/PCI-E/M.2/etc.) to connect to the working machine. If you have another machine, it will be much easier to do one of the first two.

Comment: For the second option any Linux live session can be used. Any Ubuntu or derivatives is likely to be much more user-friendlier and way more featured than DSL.

Comment: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/744explains how to create a LiveUSB of Linux Mint, which https://freegeek.org has found to be the friendliest Linux distro. It's easy.

Comment: I said DSL because it’s more likely to fit on any USB drive OP has (the link I gave says min 64 MB), but the above comments are definitely true and should work if the USB drive is around 1 GB or higher

Comment: BSOD will not affect your personal data, just try to reboot comptuer again to check if it is avaiable to boot normally or boot into safe mode to copy data out. Or we could tear disk down to plug in other computer for copy data out.

Comment: I've created a bootable DVD. When booting from it, I can install Windows or select 'Repair your computer'. If I select the latter, what should I select. I can't restore to an older date as there are no restore points. I've tried Startup Repair, however I receive the same original BSOD. ...Would installing Windows delete all my original files on my hard drive?

Comment: Yes it would. After you tried Startup Repair, did you try Safe Mode? If Startup Repair was allowed to do its thing, at least Safe Mode should work. If you do manage to get into Safe Mode, feel free to back anything up, then go to Settings->Update & Security->Recovery, and click Get Started under Reset this PC, and pick Keep my files, which will remove most programs but leave your files in your user folder.

Comment: @SithSiri Tried Safe Mode and that didn't work. Ended up taking out the hard drive. - https://i.imgur.com/WMwCwGc.jpg I need a 3.5 SATA enclosure? The files I want are within a password protected user account. I'd still be able to access them if I connect the drive to a Mac?

Comment: If your drive didn’t have BitLocker enabled (only on Windows Pro) then yes you will.